# Camera Movement and Objects Position - Plataform Game + Processing + Box2d

Tags: box2d, processing, game-physics

I'm developing a simple plataform game such as mario/sonic.
For this I've decided to use Box2D + Processing. Everything was running ok until I decided to follow the main character with a camera.After that, the plataform in the middle of the scenery didn't stayed anymore in the right poistion on the physics universe. I already tried lots of things but I falied in every attempt. So i'm here hehe.
Here's the Git Hub of the code:
https://github.com/Pedroglp/jogoDev
All the comments are written in portuguese br, so be free to ask anything.
Sorry about my poor english and thank you for your attetion.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally realized how to fix it :
I just added:
pushMatrix();
translate(cameraPosition.x - distanceTranslated.x , cameraPosition.y - distanceTranslated.y);
//code to draw all the world objects
popMatrix();

At the character movement the code should stay:

```
  pushMatrix();
  translate(100,200);
  rotate(-angle);
  fill(127);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(2);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  rect(0,0,altura,largura);
  popMatrix();
```

where 100 and 200 its where the camera is fixed.